# Graph Construction

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to create a graph with 10 vertices, where each vertex has degree of 3  and any two vertices are connected by a path of not more than 2 edges and loops and parallel edges aren't allowed. I've tried constructing a bipartite graph of sorts but had no success. Any help in solving would be appreciated, and thank you in advance!.

Comment: There exist a unique such graph, it won't be bipartite though.

Comment: Start with a tree that includes all the needed 2-edge paths from a given vertex, and then try adding edges to create the rest of the needed paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "Possible" . . . .

**[[ thanks to User Karl for high-lighting that ! ! ]]**

Consider Node 1 connecting to Node 2 , Node 3 & Node 4. It has used up the 3 edges to make it Degree 3.

Then Node 2 can connect to Node 5 & Node 6 , making it Degree 3.
Likewise Node 3 can connect to Node 7 & Node 8 , making it Degree 3.
Likewise Node 4 can connect to Node 9 & Node 10 , making it Degree 3.

This is the only way to make Node 1 connect to all other Nodes with Path length 2.

Okay , at the moment , we can see that Distance from Node 2 to Node 7 is 3 , that is , that Path requires 3 Edges.
Same Issue with the Paths connecting Node 2 to Nodes 8 & 9 & 10.
There is no way to make Paths with length 2 to connect such Nodes via Node 1.

**[[ UPDATE : I did not see the Connections from the other Nodes. thanks to User Karl for high-lighting that. ]]**

Okay , we can then go the other way , avoiding Node 1 , to make the connections :
Node 2 to Node 7 via Node 5.
Node 2 to Node 8 via Node 6.

We can then make the last Connections like :
Node 2 to Node 9 via Node 5.
Node 2 to Node 10 via Node 6.
Node 3 to Node 9 via Node 7.
Node 3 to Node 10 via Node 8.

That will make all the Nodes have Degree 3.

Hence , the Over-all Question has Positive Answer . . . .

Except for minor re-ordering & re-numbering , the Answer seems unique.

Comment: But we can add edges among nodes 5,6,7,8,9,10...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: As @Karl and @Prem said, start with the following tree.

[image]

Now add edges to the leaves so that the graph is $3$-regular and the distance between any two vertices is at most $2$.